# Event in a text widget when i stop writing with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to execute a function when i stop writing in a text widget. So I use the bind method but I have no found an event to do what I have to do !

I do this :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

main = Tk()
main.resizable(width=False, height=False)
main.title("Test")
main.geometry("700x255")

entry = Text(main, wrap=WORD, relief=FLAT, font=helv36, padx=14, pady=15)
entry.place(x='20', y='50')

entry2 = Text(main, width=34, height=9, wrap=WORD, state=DISABLED, relief=FLAT, font=helv36, padx=14, pady=15)
entry2.place(x='380', y='50')


def traduire(event):
    contents = entry.get(1.0, END)
        entry2.config(state=NORMAL)
        entry2.delete(1.0, END)
        if var.get() == "Détecter la langue":
            auto = translator.detect(contents)
            try:
                result = translator.translate(contents, src=auto.lang, dest=langue[var2.get()])
                entry2.insert(END, result.text)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            result = translator.translate(contents, src=langue[var.get()], dest=langue[var2.get()])
            entry2.insert(END, result.text)
        entry2.config(state=DISABLED)


entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', traduire)

main.mainloop()
```

but the function traduire is execute when I release a key but i want to execute this function only when I stopped writing text ;)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Could you provide a simple copy-paste minimum working example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) This way you motivate more people to help you because it makes it easy for them to help you.

Comment: how do you 'stop' writing?

Comment: when i don't press key during 1second after writing text

Comment: On every keypress, schedule a call to `traduire()` one second later using `.after()` - and also cancel the previous scheduled call, if there was one.

Comment: How can i do for cancel the previous scheduled call ?

Comment: @CodingFR I think you may want to use sched library.

Answer (score 1):

Like jasonharper suggested in the comment, one way to execute `traduire` 1s after the user stopped writing text is to use `after` to schedule the execution of `traduire` in 1s and cancel this execution if another key is pressed, using `after_cancel`. This way, `traduire` will actually be executed only if the user has not pressed any key for 1s.

My suggestion is to bind `<KeyRelease>` to the following `stop_writing` function:

```
stop_writing_id = ''  # store id of the scheduled call to traduire

def stop_writing(event):
    global stop_writing_id
    main.after_cancel(stop_writing_id)  # cancel previous scheduling of traduire
    stop_writing_id = main.after(1000, traduire)  # wait 1s and execute traduire
```